# paint method not working inside while loop in swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, thread-sleep

I have two classes. I try to move circle. When I type a  `break` statement in Game.java  it draws a circle for me without movement. That's fine. However when I want to move circle(by deleting `break` it displays nothing. I dont know how to debug that. I found out program is not going inside paint method when I use while without `break;` statement.
Can anybody also tell me the way how to debug problem like that. Thanks in advance

**App.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class App extends JFrame {

    App() {

        JFrame jf = new JFrame(); 
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jf.add(jp);
        jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        jf.setTitle("Chain Reactor Game");
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);

        Game game = new Game();
        jp.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        jf.setJMenuBar(menuBar.createMenuBar());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
         * oracle recommendation to run swing applications in special thread    
         * they suggest it during thread implementation
         */

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new App();          
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Game.java**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        System.out.println("im goint to filloval now");
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
    }
    public Game() {

        while(true) {

            moveBall();
            repaint();
            try {
                System.out.println("inside thread");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        break;     // if i delete this line it not drawing. Why is that ?

        }
    }
    private void moveBall() {
        x = x + 1;
        y = y + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/);[Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: Hope it all helps ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you leave the `break;` in you have an infinite loop. It will never end, meaning that the line `Game game = new Game();` will never return, meaning that the next line, which adds the `Game` to the `JPanel` will never run, which is why nothing is drawn on the screen. To get this to work, you need to create the GUI, and then perform the drawing.

One way to get this to work is to create a new `Thread` to perform the continual drawing:

```
public Game() {
    (new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            draw();
        }
     ).start();
 }

private void draw() {
    while(true) {
        moveBall();
        repaint();
        try {
            System.out.println("inside thread");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, since you are setting up the GUI on the Swing thread, you could run the drawing on the main thread.

Comment: if I make for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) { ... }  and I place inside for loop what I have in while loop result is the same. Infinite loop doesn't make difference. On the end of the day that circle will be acting like a bouncing ball and I have to keep it in infinite loop

Comment: Yes, but all the drawing is happening before it is displayed. You need to display the `Game` and then start drawing.

Comment: Don't forget, Swing is not thread safe, there have been some "rumours" about issues with calling `repaint` outside of the EDT in Java 8

Answer (score 4):

You need to get that while loop out of your Swing event thread as it's tying up the thread preventing Swing from performing its drawing functions or user interactions. You're basically stepping on the Swing event thread, violating Swing concurrency rules. Use a Swing Timer instead for simple animations which was built for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

Let's break the code down...

The program starts here...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*
     * oracle recommendation to run swing applications in special thread    
     * they suggest it during thread implementation
     */

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new App();          
        }
    });
}
```

This is good, it starts the GUI within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, as described in [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)...

Next, the `App` is constructed...

```
App() {

    JFrame jf = new JFrame(); 
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jf.add(jp);
    jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    jf.setSize(500, 500);
    jf.setTitle("Chain Reactor Game");
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setVisible(true);

    Game game = new Game();
    jp.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    jf.setJMenuBar(menuBar.createMenuBar());
}
```

Okay, this "seems" okay, but if we take a closer look at `Game`

```
public Game() {

    while(true) {

        moveBall();
        repaint();
        try {
            System.out.println("inside thread");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    break;     // if i delete this line it not drawing. Why is that ?

    }
}
```

Ah, here's a problem...the `while` is been executed within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, the EDT is used to process events and help schedule repaints, any thing that blocks the EDT will prevent it from, amongst other things, painting the UI

Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Now, you have a catch 22 situation here, Swing is a single threaded framework AND is NOT thread safe, this means that you can do long running/block process, but you also can't update the UI from outside the Event Dispatching Thread.

A simple solution in your case is to replace the `while-loop` with a `javax.swing.Timer`

```
public Game() {
    javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(2000, new javax.swing.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(javax.swing.ActionEvent evt) {
            moveBall();
            repaint();
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}
```

Take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details...

As a side note, it's typically recommended to use `paintComponent` to perform custom painting over `paint`.  Painting is a complex series of method calls, anything you can do to prevent screwing it up will keep your hair in place...

Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details